# aspnet core json ignore duplicate fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, json-serialization

How do I ignore duplicate fields?

For example I have this raw json `{ "Value": 3, "Name": "Test", "value": "irrelevant" }`

I would like to ignore **value** because my target type has `public int Value { get; set; }`

We have this kind of issue on most of the data from the client side views. In asp.net core, how do we instruct the json serializer to use the property that matches the type in the target?

Cheers,

Comment: Your example json seems to be invalid (value is not quoted?)... Do you have multiple members just differing in case?

Comment: Fixed the typo and added the quotes. Yes, I have multiple members just differing in case.

Comment: If you are using Json.NET, perhaps you can add [JsonIgnore] attribute to the fields you wish to exclude from serialization...

Comment: [JsonIgnore] is applied on the target clr type. In this case I don't want to ignore it, I want to deserialize it but as an integer. So if a literal string is encountered it should ignore it when the conversion to integer fails.

Comment: Well I guess the issue here is that the json is invalid(an error occured during deserialization). And it seems like the general consensus is to not sugarcoat the issue and invalidate the request instead of moving on with a probably broken data.

Comment: looks like you cannot do this with current version of Json.NET: [issues/815: Provide a way to do case-sensitive property deserialization](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/815)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible.

Assuming this JSON:

```
{ 
   "Value": 3, 
   "Name": "Test", 
   "value": "irrelevant" 
}
```

And this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }         
}
```

JSON.NET will deserialize as follows:

1. `Value = 3`
2. `Name = "Test"`
3. `Value = "irrelevant"`

The deserializer doesn't have a "state" so it doesn't care if `Value` was previously deserialized; it simply assigns the properties as it goes.

The reason you're getting an error is that your class defines `Value` as an `int`. This results in the deserializer executing:

1. `Value = 3`
2. `Name = "Test"`
3. `Value = "irrelevant"` <--- throw exception because `int` can't be set to a `string` value.

Comment: Do you know if we can change this behavior so that the deserialziation proceeds even if an exception was thrown at any step?